# Object.keys map return object Object instead value in text input form in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, forms, object

I'm trying to get some values from the JSON array on some http-address. Therefore, when I put from the map in the input field, I got an Object instead of a value. Outside the input field, it works fine.

```
    <FormGroup>
         <Label for="description">Description</Label>
         <Input type="text" name="description" id="description" value={Object.keys(item.storeByClothes).map(clothes =>{return <p>{item.storeByClothes[clothes].description}</p>})}
           onChange={this.handleChange} autoComplete="description"/>
    </FormGroup>
{Object.keys(item.storeByClothes).map(clothes =>{return <p>{item.storeByClothes[clothes].description}</p>})}
```

Inside `<FormGroup>` I got the Object. External is a necessary value.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What can you tell us about your <FormGroup>, <Label> and <Input> components? Did you build them? Are they from a library? We'll need that info to know their default behavior with the props you've passed them.

Comment: I think I had a syntax error. I removed the tags and return - operator, and now work fine. Thanks, your remark has turned my attention to check the code again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

currently JSX transpiler converts `<p>...` into React component (object) and then passes it into `input` as its `value`. To display variable's content browser calls `.toString()` method. so finally you see "[Object object]" there. Depending on your needs you need different changes made.

Say if you expect to see HTML markup inside input(like a string) you should make it string(say using template strings):

```
.map(el => `<p>....`
```

Or you just should not put it into `<input value` if you need to see it as live HTML markup